# Set labels at RadarChartData

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using Charts v3.2.2 framework by danielgindi for iOS and macOS to draw a `RadarChartView`. There is a [github repository](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/master/ChartsDemo-macOS) that provides an example xcode project including Playgrounds. One is for `RadarChartView`.

Following the example I can set `RadarChartData` with two different `RadarChartDataSet`s

```
var chartView = RadarChartView(frame: rect)
let data = RadarChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])
chartView.data = data
```

It shows a chart like this:

[image]

The green labels set to x-axis are numbers from 0.0 to 4.0, but they should be string labels.

I cannot figure out how to set these labels that should be drawn around the `RadarChart` at the end of each web line. I guess it should be something like this:

```
data.setLabels("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York", "Tokio")
```

But this isn't working although it is a feature of class `RadarChartData` to set the desired labels.

Can somebody help me with that issue?

EDIT: complete code example

```
import Cocoa
import Charts
import PlaygroundSupport

let r = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400)
var chartView = RadarChartView(frame: r)
// General settings
chartView.webColor = NSUIColor.lightGray
chartView.innerWebColor = NSUIColor.lightGray
chartView.webAlpha = 1.0
// xAxis settings
let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
xAxis.xOffset = 0.0
xAxis.yOffset = 0.0
xAxis.labelTextColor = NSUIColor.green
xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true

// yAxis settings
let yAxis = chartView.yAxis
yAxis.labelCount = 5
yAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
yAxis.axisMaximum = 80.0
yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
// Legend settings
let legend = chartView.legend
// ... (irrelevant)

// Description
chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = true
chartView.chartDescription?.text = "Radar demo"
chartView.chartDescription?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

// RadarChartDataEntry
let mult = 80.0
let min = 20.0
let cnt = 5

var entries1 = [RadarChartDataEntry]()
var entries2 = [RadarChartDataEntry]()

for i in 1...cnt
{
  let values1 = (Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(mult))) + min)
  entries1.append(RadarChartDataEntry(value: values1, data: "a" as AnyObject))
  let values2 = (Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(mult))) + min)
  entries2.append(RadarChartDataEntry(value: values2, data: "b" as AnyObject))
}

// RadarChartDataSet
let set1 = RadarChartDataSet(entries: entries1, label: "Last Week")
set1.drawFilledEnabled = true
set1.fillAlpha = 0.7
set1.lineWidth = 2.0
set1.drawHighlightCircleEnabled = true
set1.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)

let set2 = RadarChartDataSet(entries: entries2, label: "This Week")
set2.drawFilledEnabled = true
set2.fillAlpha = 0.7
set2.lineWidth = 2.0
set2.drawHighlightCircleEnabled = true
set2.setDrawHighlightIndicators(false)

// RadarChartData
let data = RadarChartData(dataSets: [set1, set2])
data.setLabels("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "New York", "Tokio")
data.setDrawValues ( true )
data.setValueTextColor(  NSUIColor.white )
chartView.data = data
chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)

// show chartView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = chartView
```

Comment: what you want on that X lables ? String as shown on image or Numbers ?

Comment: I want string labels instead of numbers (green values).

Comment: Can you add more code from your chart setup and dataset code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `IAxisValueFormatter` `func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {}` function.

Like below:

**Step1: Customize your xAxis with custom formatter.**

```
let xValues = ["X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"]
let chartFormatter = RadarChartFormatter(labels: xValues)
let xAxis = XAxis()
xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
self.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter
```

**Step2: Implement Custom formatter with below method.**

```
private class RadarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    
    var labels: [String] = []
    
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if Int(value) < labels.count {
            return labels[Int(value)]
        }else{
            return String("")
        }
    }
    
    init(labels: [String]) {
        super.init()
        self.labels = labels
    }
}
```

You will get below output in your RadarCharView:

[image]

Hope this will help you to get your custom labels on Radar chart!

Comment: **IAxisValueFormatter** protocol was renamed to **AxisValueFormatter**.